# Find based on association, but don't include association in result in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

In short, I want to find something in a table using the `include: [{ model, where }]` method, but not actually "include" the model I'm including.

I have two models, with a one-to-many association, `Part` and `Set`. I'm finding `Part`s that belong to `Set`s based on the `slug` of the `Set`. Like this:

```
yield Part.findAll({
  where: {
    slug: 'my-part'
  },
  include : [{
    model: Set,
    where: {
      slug: 'my-set'
    }
  }]...
```

This gives me an array like this:

```
[
  {
    is: 1,
    slug: 'my-part',
    body: 'this is my nice part',
    Set: {
      slug: 'my-set',
      body: 'what a set',
      id: 1
    }
  }
]
```

I just want to get a result like this:

```
[
  {
    is: 1,
    slug: 'my-part',
    body: 'this is my nice part'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try settings `attributes: []` on the include:

```
yield Part.findAll({
  where: {
    slug: 'my-part'
  },
  include : [{
    attributes: [],
    model: Set,
    where: {
      slug: 'my-set'
    }
  }]...
```